# Is continuous focus a 4.0-only feature?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, camera, 4.2-jelly-bean, focus

The http://www.android.com/about/ice-cream-sandwich/ page details that Android 4.0 "Ice Cream Sandwich" introduced two interesting features for Camera: **“continuous focus”** and **“zero shutter lag exposure”**.

Have both of these features been removed or disabled post 4.0?  My Galaxy Nexus seems to have neither since the 4.1 and 4.2 over-the-air upgrades.

Holding a 4.2 Galaxy Nexus still and taking a picture with auto settings and without flash in a relatively-very-well-lit nightclub takes about 3 seconds, and taking another picture right away takes another 3 seconds, seemingly indicating that both features are completely absent in stock 4.2.

Comment: I wonder if that lag is due to the new HDR feature.

Comment: There is no HDR on Galaxy Nexus (dual-core 1.2GHz and 1GB RAM are not enough for HDR these days?), and the lag seems to be a carry-on from 4.1.

Comment: I have CM11 running on an OnePlus One and the CyanogenMod Camera has the option to use continuius focus. You could try it from the Play Store http://goo.gl/2k7qm8 or installing the apk-file http://goo.gl/q02TdC

Answer (score 0):

In low light(or in very bright light) scenario, '**Zero shutter lag**' feature won't work  because the camera module and the software together will do some heavy work to capture picture really good. Try taking picture in good lighting condition(during daytime) to test Zero shutter lag functionality.

In some phones, **Continuous focus** makes use of accelerometer sensor to detect the movement of the phones to refocus the camera. This may not work when there is very slight movement. You can also check this during good lightning conditions

Comment: This is an invalid advice, because the feature clearly used to work, and then stopped with the "upgrade"; they've even removed all mentions of this feature ever being there in the device, clearly trying to cover up the fact that they've messed it up in the subsequent software "upgrades"; the best picture would be if it'd just use infinity by default in low light, instead of being so slow with the stupid and needless (re)focus as for the subjects of the photo to be gone for good.